# Command not found error throwed about function on shell script called with bash and curl after sudo su

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting

When doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
function01() {
    echo "Func01"
}
function02() {
    echo "Func02"
}
function03() {
    echo "Func03"
}
clear
function01
function02
#sudo su
function03
```

and calling as:

```
curl http://192.168.1.1:80/myScript.sh | sudo bash
```

or

```
curl http://192.168.1.1:80/myScript.sh | bash
```

It run ok but if uncommenting the line:

```
#sudo su
```

above then it throw the error:

```
bash: line 1: function03: command not found
```

Comment: Erm, what are you even expecting `sudo su` to do in that context?  BTW, you really should use `sudo -i`, not sudo su`.

Comment: @Zoredache There is a block of code that doesnt run with just sudo context then doing sudo su to become root and execute the block, I dont know about sudo -i , i will try with it, thanks. By the way the code i wrote is really wrong ?

Comment: If you are expecting `sudo` to be able to run that function, it isn't going to work. Those functions exist in the scope of the current shell running that script.  If you use `sudo` that spawns a completely new shell.  Your functions are not copied to the new shell.

Comment: @Zoredache Im doing sudo echo 'something' > /etc/fstab and it dont work, need be with real root and I tried using sudo -i on the minimal example as you told on this body question but the error remains the same

Comment: @Zoredache understood, then sudo su is creating another context, then i believe need call sudo -i before calling script with curl/bash and removing all sudo after it, thanks

Comment: Another person with echo /etc problems: https://stackoverflow.com/q/84882